# Is it possible to use liquibase in AWS ECS Fargate?

Tags: liquibase, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I ask because I've tried and failed.   The problem seems to be that liquibase needs information about the host it is running on to lock and write to the DATABASECHANGELOG.

Thus, when I bring up my spring-boot application in an ECS Fargate cluster, I see this:

018-01-12 19:34:03.406 ERROR 6 --- [ main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/mlb/best/config/LiquibaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at .springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at com.mlb.best.Application.main(Application.java:31) [classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [application.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [application.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [application.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [application.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]
at liquibase.sqlgenerator.SqlGeneratorFactory.(SqlGeneratorFactory.java:40) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.sqlgenerator.SqlGeneratorFactory.getInstance(SqlGeneratorFactory.java:54) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.executor.AbstractExecutor.applyVisitors(AbstractExecutor.java:23) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.access$700(JdbcExecutor.java:36) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:345) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query(JdbcExecutor.java:135) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query(JdbcExecutor.java:143) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:151) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:166) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForInt(JdbcExecutor.java:187) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForInt(JdbcExecutor.java:182) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.isDatabaseChangeLogLockTableInitialized(StandardLockService.java:118) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.init(StandardLockService.java:94) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:188) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.waitForLock(StandardLockService.java:154) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:186) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:353) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:317) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.net.UnknownHostException: 19f647ae563e: 19f647ae563e: unknown error
at liquibase.sqlgenerator.core.LockDatabaseChangeLogGenerator.(LockDatabaseChangeLogGenerator.java:32) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 19f647ae563e: 19f647ae563e: unknown error
at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]
at liquibase.util.NetUtil.getLocalHostName(NetUtil.java:41) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
at liquibase.sqlgenerator.core.LockDatabaseChangeLogGenerator.(LockDatabaseChangeLogGenerator.java:29) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
... 48 common frames omitted
***Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 19f647ae563e: unknown error*
*at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]*
*at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]*
*at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]*
*at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500) ~[na:1.8.0_92-internal]***
... 50 common frames omitted

Is there some way to get around this or must I punt and use AWS ECS EC2?  Normally I'd fix this by inspecting my /etc/hosts to be sure there is a localhost defined there.  But not sure how I do that with fargate.

Comment: Which version of liquibase are you using? Here is a liquibase-jira ticket where something similar happens: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2344. Maybe you just need to update liquibase? If not, maybe you can create a ticket? As Nathan said hostname is only for informational purposes. So I guess liquibase should not fail if it can not get a hostname.

Comment: I was running 3.3.2.   Have updated that to 3.5.3 and that seems to have resolved the problem.  Thank you @jens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above, using the latest version of the liquibase-core resolved the issue.